# Tools like Litmus Paper

Tags: everyday-chemistry, sensor

Litmus papers are used to test acidity and alkalinity of a fluid. Are there other paper-based tools to test for other stuff like dissolved oxygen, presence of toxicity, electric potential etc?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Chemistry SE. This is good question, it reminded me of paper based battery indicator that worked just like mercury-type thermometer so when the battery potential is full the paper showed full range and if the battery is low then partial range. I can also imagine the plastic based coating on the mugs that turns colorless revealing a picture when hot fluid is poured, there are inexpensive methods to test for various properties.

Comment: Pregnancy test kits. Lead paint test kits.

Comment: @metron, yes i know temperature can be sensed by such materials but wasnt aware of paper-based battery indicator

Comment: @JonCuster what is lead paint test kit? is it also paper based?

Comment: Yes, available at your local hardware store. Moisten and wipe a painted object, turns color if lead is picked up from it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik this is valid answer to my question. I am considering writing a paper on all the test papers, you read my mind :) Thanks.

Comment: @JhonnyS, I've enlarged the comment a bit and made it an answer.

Comment: There are paper thermometers (which actually employ a type of liquid crystals) that change colour and show temperature

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti well thats quite interesting actually its quite remarkable that we have all these tests available not in sophisticated devices but dispensable papers for easy home chemistry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to find a slew of test papers and strips online. For example, a quick search of Amazon for "test papers" turned up chlorine test strips for pools and sanitation, glucose test strips for diabetes, [phenylthiourea](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01A9DOL9I) genetic-linked taste tests, [UV-C dose test cards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088TSB1BF), lead acetate paper test for $\ce{H2S}$, [WBC and nitrite test strips](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00854L57U) for UTI... You could write a paper on all the test papers available.

Increasingly, medicine is making use of paper tests because of ease of distribution, storage and use, particularly important in rural location and during emergencies.

BTW, you can make a test paper for polarity testing, and for detection of peroxides, by dipping filter paper into a suspension of starch and potassium iodide, $\ce{KI}$, rather than [buy it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001DBH4CW). Dampen and [use it as you would a potato](https://thehappyscientist.com/content/potato-polarity) to determine the polarity of an electric cell.